# Omniauth proxy rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, proxy, omniauth

Does anybody know how I configure omniauth to accept http proxy settings?

I could do this lower down the stack either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by setting the default proxy in the oauth consumer class...its a bit of a hack but it works.  Omniauth probably has a setting, as oauth has, but time was against me and this works fine.

Rgds,

slothishtype

Comment: slotishtype, could you give that example?

Comment: I wish I could but that project is old, and the code obsolete. I used a monkey patch if I recall.